# cluster geometry differs from original geometry (has an offset, but why?)

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

So I have a cluster layer, and when I click on the cluster, it zooms to the cluster using getClusterExpansionZoom and the feature geometry from the click event. However, there is a slight offset which I am failing to understand compared to the original feature's coordinates. In this specific case I have a cluster of 2 overlapping points at -151.192568, 28.6140075, but the cluster's geometry is reported to be at -151.19384765625, 28.613459424004418, causing the zoom not to be centered correctly on the cluster on the lowest zoom level (clusterMaxZoom and maxZoom, 17).

Why is there a difference? TIA.